# multicriteria sorting using sort command

Tags: shell, sorting

How to sort the following lines using the second and third fields as keys (field separator is ".")
e. g. given  :

```
17.10.19 xx 14.11.19
19.01.21 xx 20.02.21
20.11.20 xx 20.12.20
21.02.21 xx 20.03.21
21.03.21 xx 18.04.21
26.06.20 xx 30.07.20
29.05.20 xx 25.06.20
30.04.20 xx 28.05.20
31.07.20 xx 03.09.20
03.04.10 xx 18.04.19
19.04.19 xx 02.05.19
03.04.20 xx 30.04.20
```

how to sort this to obtain :

```
03.04.10 xx 18.04.19
19.04.19 xx 02.05.19
17.10.19 xx 14.11.19
03.04.20 xx 30.04.20
30.04.20 xx 28.05.20
29.05.20 xx 25.06.20
26.06.20 xx 30.07.20
31.07.20 xx 03.09.20
20.11.20 xx 20.12.20
19.01.21 xx 20.02.21
21.02.21 xx 20.03.21
21.03.21 xx 18.04.21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort -t. -k3n -k2n -k1n file
```

Start of output:

```
03.04.10 xx 18.04.19
19.04.19 xx 02.05.19
17.10.19 xx 14.11.19
...
```

I can't really say if that `xx` would affect the order.